# Can we share worklight server Install Directory for all the cluster nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, ibm-mobilefirst, application-server, worklight-server

Planning to install Worklight on a cluster. Right now we installed Worklight Directory on all nodes in the same folder but Can we install the Worklight Server Directory on shared folder and refer to the shared installed directory on all the server nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that defeat the clustering approach? If whichever location that holds the shared Worklight folder goes down, your cluster will go down as well, because all nodes that require Worklight, won't have it available, thus no replication between databases, connection is down,  all sort of errors because Worklight Server is not available, etc...

Unless this "directory" you're referring to is not operational during runtime?

Comment: Maybe they need a cluster because the application server machines have an availability of 95%, whereas the file server (which serves the directories mounted on all application server machines) has an availability of 99.9%.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebSphere Application Server (Network Deployment) Full Profile, you need to install the Worklight Server product only on one machine, namely the machine which contains the deployment manager. Then proceed as documented [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_installing_wl_server_into_was_nd.html). The war files, jar files, and configuration changes will be propagated from the deployment manager to the nodes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the way i got this working(though probably not supported) is

1. to have the two servers point at the same DB.
2. get the two servers to point to the same worklight.home directory.  I did this by modifying the jvm.options file and adding -Dworklight.home="f:\worklightShare".

We are running this in testing with light load, so im not sure how it will do in production.